# How to fix error message when hosting a website on IIS with Orchard CMS?

Tags: iis, hosting, orchardcms, website-hosting

I am working on **orchard CMS** and trying to host website on **IIS**, after hosting on **IIS** it's throwing me an error:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]
      Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]
      Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[58]
      Creating key {bd490136-0c6d-4132-887b-1cb18ffd9f33} with creation date 2023-05-19 08:20:42Z, activation date 2023-05-19 08:20:42Z, and expiration date 2023-08-17 08:20:42Z.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {bd490136-0c6d-4132-887b-1cb18ffd9f33} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2023-05-19 13:50:42.4020|INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
2023-05-19 13:50:42.4028|INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
```

Please help.

Tried with multiple solutions but not working.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on this message, try to debug the cause using IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool, this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.